# Typescript bug? Function accepts Object with missing prop when defined to accept union of type A and B where B extends A

Tags: typescript

This might be a bug or me not understanding union types. Take a look at this code:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210518#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgfgC5kBnMKUAcwG4dkAjIhge2YBsI4RaBfLLUJFiIUAIWQQAHpBAATEmmy5Jxeqw5dauAJ7EyFEDSx8sMAK4gEYYMxDIADgbABhVlFkAKe2GLoAPsiiAJSYdAi2JOwQAHRszJQeAEQAKgAWKOHM7qBwkADkCpLIAG5wbGYowAqJyADUDmDRcEFayOEgkRyx8UlpGW6yOfkK2iVlFchVyDX13tH0LcZYjoKuWZ4YeMSJcCSyMIkANAzE5BM8i8tOa%204eGHDbu-tHyCrI8GwkEBfUQA)

​

```
interface A {
  a?: string;
  b?: boolean;
}

interface B extends A{
  x: boolean;
  y: string;
}

function printCoord(pt: A | B) {
  console.log("The coordinate's x value is " + pt.a);
  console.log("The coordinate's y value is " + pt.b);
}
printCoord({ a: "asdf", b: true });

printCoord({a: "asdf", x: false});
```

The last line should not compile, because the presence of  `x` enforces type `B`, but `y` is missing so it should actually be invalid.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a function even, `const test:A|B={ a: "asdf", x: false }` also valid. And even `const test:A|B={ a: undefined, x: false }`. Only if you remove the `a` the magic breaks. TS is okay with a union as long as the value has all the intersection fields, which to me means that not being able to do  `const test:A|B={ x: false }` is a bug, while your case is the expected behaviour. Anyways, is it causing you any issues?

Answer (score 1):

The union type is used to declare a type that is either one (or even both).

example:

```
interface A {
  a1: string;
  a2: string;
}

interface B {
  b1: string;
  b2: string;
}

const e1: A|B = {a1: "1", a2:"1"}  // valid
const e2: A|B = {b1: "1", b2:"1"}  // valid
const e3: A|B = {a1: "1", b1:"1"}  // invalid
```

In your example, you are trying to assign `{a: "asdf", x: false}` to `A | B`.
since type `A` accepts pretty much anything (even `{}`) then `{a: "asdf", x: false}` can be assigned to `A | B`.

The reason it doesn't throw an error about the fact that there is a `B` property there is because `A | B` allows the value to be a mix of both. It has to be at least A or B, but can "inspire" to be both.

that's why this is also valid

```
printCoord({ a: "asdf" });  // valid
```

Comment: But A doesn't accept just anything. Change the function to only accept A and the last line will fail because x is not part of A. So this leaves only B as a possible type which would require both x and y to be present.